# Error extencion mysqli

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Al entrar a mi phpMyAdmin me he dado cuenta que me saltaba este error.

> phpMyAdmin  - Error

> No se encontró la extensión mysqli. Revisa la configuración de PHP. Revise  nuestra documentación para mas información.

después me eh dado cuenta que mis paginas web que utilizan MYSQL no estarían funcionado (Se quedarían en blanco)

Me fije antes de publicar este post pero ya intente descargar la librería php-mysql y php8.1-mysql

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería demasiado.

Un saludo

Comment: puedes añadir tu codigo para una mejor ayuda

Comment: Qué estás usando para instalar apache/php/msyql? WAMP, XAMP, Laragon...

Comment: el esta usando phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

La librería [php-mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php) , se encuentra obsoleta desde hace ya mucho tiempo, la librería que deberías instalar es `mysqli` o `PDO_MySQL` para linux es bien sencillo solo deberías ejecutar desde una terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install phpX.X-mysqli
```

si usas WAMP deberías chequear que esta estas usando la versión mas actualizada y por ultimo debes verificar que la librería se encuentra operativa en tu servidor descomentando la linea

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

quitando el punto y coma de tu archivo de configuración `php.ini`,
en el caso de linux:

```
;extension=php_mysqli.so
```

y finalmente solo debes reiniciar el servicio web de tu servidor.

Comment: Hola, ahora me salta el siguiente error al intentar descargar la librería.

https://i.imgur.com/ZJBfER4.png

Comment: bueno ahí dice que debes ser especifico con la versión que deseas instalar, primero verifica que versión de php estas usando mediante ``php -v``, luego según corresponda pones ``sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqli`` o la versión que corresponda.